# Alt + Key on Textbox with non-English keyboard should add letter but it doesn't

Tags: wpf, alt

On a german keyboard you would add `[` by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> and `]` via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>. This is not working in a WPF textbox or richtextbox.

When creating a new application and adding textbox, the combinations using the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key are working, not the combinations for the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Adding the textbox to a usercontrol and a toolbar and putting everything inside of a scrollviewer also disables the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key combinations.

My workaround is for now to add an event handler for the `previewkeydown` event and add the characters code-wise. However, that does not feel right. I assume that I am missing something very basic here but cannot find it. All methods I found lead to a full deactivation of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key functionality. Would appreciate if somebody could give me a hint.

Answer (score 1):

When using the German (DE) Keyboard layout you **MUST** use the <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> key and **NOT** the <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> key and then press <kbd>8</kbd> or <kbd>9</kbd>.

This is how  Microsoft Windows configures other coutries keyboards. The <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> serves as the Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key while the right is dedicated to special characters.

You need the a "windows" <kbd>alt</kbd> key for windows key combinations like <kbd>Control + Alt + Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd>, etc.

Comment: :facepalm: Checked again in Word and other text editors. The left Alt key is indeed not supposed to work in the way I thought. Thank you.